# How to create pagination on return json data in laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel-5, pagination, laravel-5.4

This is data that comes from API but i don't know how to paginate that data so i can display it on view. 
This is the Controller function:-

```
    $client =new Client();

    $req = $client->request('GET','https://api.sandbox.amadeus.com/v1.2/flights/affiliate-search?apikey=lFzCNHVGO7NkDJVeUzb2ejHvIS1dIA4A&origin='.$origin.'&destination='.$destination.'&departure_date='.$dateDeparture.'&return_date='.$dateReturn.'&adults='.$adultsCount.'&children='.$ChildCount);

    $data = $req->getBody()->getContents();

    $flights = \GuzzleHttp\json_decode($data);

    foreach ($flights->results as $flight)
    {
            dd($flight->deep_link);        
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem? What do you want to do? I see no clearly defined question. Also, we do not know the content of the response, so you need to include that unless you know someone that is good at guessing.

Comment: the data comes from live API and the data is different on every request  i want to paginate it so i can use it on my view

Comment: Still does not answer any of my questions. Is the API data returned as a whole, or limited to some entries per request? How do you do pagination there? Do you wish to implement pagination in your laravel application? How does the API response look? The question as it is right now is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you follow these steps in order to create paginations you need to create manual pagination I think

1. convert the json response into an array.
2. Create a manual pagination by following this reference from the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator)